# php files download instead of running php scripts

Tags: php, mamp

I am Thomas. And this is my first post!

I have downloaded MAMP and created a very simple html form which references a very simple php file. I have put the php file into MAMP's htdocs folder, and linked it to the html document accordingly. I do not know where to put the html file. When I use google chrome, hitting the submit button on my form downloads the php file. And in Safari, the page advances to a screen showing the code displayed in raw format.

I do not know what I need to do to make MAMP do the php. Is it a file location issue? Can someone please help?

Thank you in advance!
Thomas

ps. I did try just to submit this in the MAMP forum, but it needs to be reviewed and expurgated by a moderator before that site will publish it. I apologize if my question is outside the typical province of this forum. Thanks again!

Comment: First of all, are you accessing your page through http://localhost?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this site. It seems that your question has been answered already, if you look to your right under "Related".

Comment: No. Based on your suggestion, I aimed my browser just at http://localhost:8888/ (port MAMP comes with) and it opened the html page and processed the php without any problem. But when I tried to make a bit of file structure inside the htdocs (htdocs/project1/html) http://localhost:8888/ still took me straight to the html file, but couldn't find the next page when I pressed submit (i had put the php file in a php folder I made and reformatted my link to the php file)

Comment: So How can I make file structure within dtdocs to keep my projects and php experiments straight?

Comment: yes, but that seems not to address the larger file structure issue within the «dtdoc» folder. thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue! Even more frustrating, it was working fine a minute ago. Then I changed the directory to use something other than htdocs, and it no longer works. Now just downloads the file.

Answer (score 0):

One of a few things:

- Your MAMP isn't running all of the services
- Your MAMP isn't configured correctly
- You file was saved in the wrong encoding format.  This usually occurs when you send a PHP file to the server through FTP and it's sent as binary instead of ASCII.  If your editor is set to a enctype that isn't supported by the web server, it won't process the file and send it to you as a download.

Comment: what possible services could my MAMP be running that it isn't? I don't understand what a service would be(?)

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what sorts of configuration could be incorrect? 
Thanks! Thomas